# Problem about Bipartite Graphs.

Tags: graph-theory

**Problem:** Prove that the only connected bipartite graphs that are chordal are trees.

**My Attempt:** Consider a connected bipartite graph $G$. This graph is a tree if and only if it does not contain a cycle. So what we need to show is that the condition of "chordality" does not allow the graph $G$ to contain cycles. However, if a bipartite graph contains cycles of length at least 6 then it can be chordal, but not necessarily a tree. For example, the graph given below is chordal and also a connected bipartite graph, yet it is not a tree.

[image]

Note: This problem is from the book Introductory Combinatorics by Richard A. Brualdi, Problem no. 44, Chapter 12. Page 502.

Comment: What definition of chordality are you using? Using the one from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_graph) your above example isn't chordal: The 4-cycle 1,5,3,6(,1) does not contain a chord.

Comment: A graph is chordal if a cycle of length 4 or more in it contains a chord, i.e. there is an edge between nonconsecutive vertices in that cycle.

Comment: There is a 6 cycle in this graph WITH a chord.

Comment: 1-4-2-5-3-6-1 is the 6- cycle and the chord is 1-5.

Comment: So the connected bipartite graph is chordal yet it is not a tree?

Comment: What you are thinking is that chordal means "There is *one* cycle of length 4 or more with a chord in it". What chordal really means is (as from Wikipedia above): "a chordal graph is one in which *all* cycles of four or more vertices have a chord" (emphasis mine).

Comment: Oohhh! I got it. But what about a bipartite graph that has cycles of length at least 6. I know that it is not possible to draw chord in a 4 cycle in a bipartite graph, but it is possible to draw a chord in 6 cycle graph.

Comment: However, that would create a 4-cycle in which we cannot draw chord and thus the bipartite graph cannot be chordal. We could generalize this argument.

Comment: Yes, you got the point.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help @Ingix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use strong induction in the number of nodes. Let $2n$  be the number of nodes, ($a_{1},a_{2},...a_{n})$ in one side and $(b_{1},b_{2},...b_{n})$ in the other. The goal is to prove that there is no cycle in your graph. Is easy to see that for n=1 and n=2 works. For n=2 you use the fact that if $[a_{i_{1}},b_{i_{1}},a_{i_{2}},b_{i_{2}}]$ is the cycle. But you cant have a chord because the only chords that are possible are the edge $a_{1}-a_{2}$ and $b_{1}-b_{2}$. Contradiction, because the graph is bipartite. now suppose n>2 and you have a cycle with more than 4 nodes. By hypothesis, the chord must break the cycle into two smallest cycles. And by strong induction you can't have a smaller cycle. So there is no cycle in the graph. And because is a connected graph with no cycles, by definition is a tree. QED